# Django Admin change widget type

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to change the widget type of my many2many relationship to "FilteredSelectMultiple"

I learned from other questions and the documentation that this should do the trick

```
admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
            forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField: {'widget': FilteredSelectMultiple},
    }
```

Unfortunatly nothing changes in the admin pages. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `formfield_overrides` isn't having any effect because you should use the model field, i.e. `models.ManyToManyField` instead of the form field, `forms.MultipleChoiceField`. However, simply switching the key to `models.ManyToManyField` won't work, because the widget [should be instantiated](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9dcfecb7c6c8285630ad271888a9ec4ba9140e3a/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L37) with the field name and a boolean `is_stacked`.

There are a couple of other approaches:

To use a `FilteredSelectMultiple` for individual fields, use the [`filter_horizonal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) or [`filter_vertical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) options.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('my_m2m_field',)
```

To override the widget for all many to many fields, you could override [`formfield_for_manytomany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany).

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        vertical = False  # change to True if you prefer boxes to be stacked vertically
        kwargs['widget'] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
            db_field.verbose_name,
            vertical,
        )
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Don't forget to register your model with your model admin.

```
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The filter_horizontal snippet would be perfect for my needs. I added it to admin.py and no change in the admin form. Is there any more code needed?

Comment: I tested the above code and it works. Did you remember to register your model admin class?

Comment: My bad. I forgot exactly that. I registered it and now it works. Thank you very much!